# How to OOA/OOD a rather complex concept?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, domain-model, use-case

I'm a novice at Object-Oriented Designing and have read some OOD books & tutorials recently. Now I'm planning to implement a video player(based on existing media api, [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/) or [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) etc) to practice what I've learned.

The idea is that given a video file, open it through certain media api, and then feed each frame to OpenGL to apply some warping transforms and finally render it via OpenGL.

To warp each frame is the main goal of writing this video player myself, since I can only apply linear transforms to a default display layer/surface with existing api.(warping is a nonlinear transform)

But I'm stuck at the beginning, the use case scenario is relatively simple:

1. User requests to open a video file
2. User plays the video

According to the book `Applying UML and Patterns`, I should extract Domain Models from the use case and those Domain Models will inspire the design of Software Models (classes). But I can see only two Domain Models from the Use case `VideoPlayer` and `VideoFile`. And their association may look like this:

```
,-------------.     plays     ,----------.
| VideoPlayer | ------------> | VideoFile|
`-------------'               `----------'
```

But the actual design of VideoPlayer is far more complex by instinct, and I can't see any clue from previous work of writing use cases and extracting Domain Models.

I think the most probable problem is that I've written the use case incorrectly -- too generic. But I can't really think of any fine grain sized things that should be in the use case and confirms to the guideline `Write use cases from the user's perspective` at the meantime.

Comment: This is a fine start, but you need to use recursive decomposition to tease more out.   You can start your design without the warping and then add that later, if that helps.  The user is viewing the video, right?  And that video is viewed as a series frames.  So the user sees the series of frames.  Something has to feed the graphics the frames, and something has to interpret frames out of the encoded video file.  Once you have that designed you can introduce warping by refactoring as needed.

Comment: @NandiinBao  Sometimes it is best to just start writing code.  It will be ugly at first but then you refactor, and refactor, and refactor.  This will give you a better understanding the library you are using and the problems you need to solve.

Comment: @Aliester and refactor and refactor and ... to infinity. Dig your own grave.

Comment: @ThomasKilian  I don't recommend this approach for production systems but when you don't understand the problem well and you are using it as a learning exercise then it can help.  I am pretty sure every decent developer has written proof of concept code to gain understanding then used that to additional knowledge to design a production worthy component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> think the most probable problem is that I've written the use case incorrectly -- too generic.

I think the problem is the idea that all your objects should exist in your Use Case. Use cases are just a guide to make sure you are designing a system based on what the user actually want/requires. But not all objects will exist in the use case.

You probably could expand on your use case, but you also will then need to look at the objects that come out of the use case study (eg `VideoFile`) and then think of what objects will that object use to implement its behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

If the 'certain API' can't do the warp because it's a nonlinear transform what good is the API doing you?

What you really need to do is to decompose the problem in front of you.

For that the kiss principle is a good one to follow.  Lets build up some capabilities.

Working on the assumption that the warp isn't something you can directly apply to a non-decoded video stream:

Do you have the ability to apply a warp to a still image?

Do you have the ability to break a video file into a set of still images (decode)?

Do you have the ability to put a set of still images into a video file (encode)?

Any one of those can be a stumbling block for you.  An attempt to do any one of them would lead to a more focused question.  Keep decomposing until you start wondering how you should organize all this work.  That's when OOD starts to help.